# Adjust distance of mouse from the bottom of the screen before the Dock re-appears

Tags: dock, settings, big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur, when I bring the mouse to the bottom of the screen, the Dock appears a bit before the mouse has completely reached the bottom. That means that a lot of times when I want to scroll horizontally by wanting to move the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the window, the Dock re-appears as I move the mouse to the horizontal scroll (but before completely reaching the bottom of the screen) which is super annoying and disruptive.

Is there a way to change the Dock behavior so it re-appears only when the mouse has completely reached the bottom of the screen?

Comment: You could avoid the issue by using Shift+scrollwheel.

Comment: I'd love to know; it is so annoying when I need to resize a window from the bottom and I can't because the dock shows instead.